# Switch keys for external keyboard

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, hardware

I use the file `~/.Xmodmap`

```
keycode 110 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 112 = Home NoSymbol Home
keycode 115 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 117 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 151 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 37  = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
```

to switch the Home key with the page-up key and the End key with the page down key. Now I plugged an external keyboard into my laptop and there the switch simply does not happen. What am I missing?